# Make strong tag left-aligned as li tag in ul tag

Tags: html, css

I have a `strong` tag in `ul` tag, like,

```
<ul>
    <strong>Whats included in strong tag</strong>
    <li>li tag 1</li>
    <li>li tag 2</li>
</ul>
```

The result shows in a website page, like

>   **Whats included in strong tag**
> - li tag
>     1
> - li tag 2

I want to make the text of the strong tag(`Whats included in strong tag`) **left-aligned** to the position of `li` tag.

Except setting up `margin` value in strong tag, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Move the strong tag outside of the UL or add a margin to the LI's?

Comment: I can not move strong tag outside of the UL due to the design pattern the architect uses in this case. Since this result will be used in Desktop and Mobile App, it will be complicated if I adjust its margin value.

Comment: Only LI are valid children of UL -- reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul . Put the strong inside of an li, and it is valid.

Comment: Thank you. However, if doing that, I need to remove the bullet from the strong tag.

Comment: `list-style: none` removes the bullet.

Comment: You'll still need to use margin-left to "undo" the padding of the ul element / the margin-left on the li element. Without knowing what other styling is present it's not possible to really comment on the other positioning.

Comment: I see. Let me think about moving the strong tag from ul tag.

Answer (score 1):

```css
li.strong{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.li1{
  margin-left:30px;
}
.li2{
  text-indent: 30px;
  list-style-type:none;
}
.li2::before{
  content:"• ";
}
.li3{
  position:relative;
  left: 30px;
}
.strong4{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
}
.li4{
  position:relative;
  top:16px;
}
.li5{
  text-align:center;
  list-style-type:none;
}
.li5::before{
  content:"• ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="strong"><strong>Whats included in strong tag</strong></li>
    <li class="li1">li tag 1</li>
    <li class="li1">li tag 2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="strong"><strong>Whats included in strong tag</strong></li>
    <li class="li2">li tag 1</li>
    <li class="li2">li tag 2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="strong"><strong>Whats included in strong tag</strong></li>
    <li class="li3">li tag 1</li>
    <li class="li3">li tag 2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="strong"><strong class="strong4">Whats included in strong tag</strong></li>
    <li class="li4">li tag 1</li>
    <li class="li4">li tag 2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="strong"><strong>Whats included in strong tag</strong></li>
    <li class="li5">li tag 1</li>
    <li class="li5">li tag 2</li>
</ul>
```

1. Use margin left on the `<li>` elements instead of `<strong>` tag.
2. Use text indent
3. Use position relative on `<li>` tags or on `<strong>` tag.
4. Use position absolute on `<strong>` and position relative on `<li>`
5. Use text align

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this has a down vote?

Comment: Most likely because of the fact that the markup is not valid

Comment: Example valid markup - <ul><li><strong>Title list</strong></li><li>List</li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

It should not be set in the first li because this would assume a sibling relationship to the preceding li elements whereas the header is more important in the hierarchy. Imagine screen-readers etc

`<strong>Strong Text!</strong>
<ul>
  <li>Other text</li>
</ul>`!

Comment: Please edit your comment to show how to do these things, or post references to documentation or instructions to do these things.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the strong text an `li` with styling to remove the bullet and shift it left.

```css
.nobullet {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nobullet"><strong>Strong Text!</strong></li>
  <li>Other text!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this margin value may be different since my project will apply to different devices(desktop and mobile app). I try to avoid using the margin setting.